# ForEach vs Map vs Reduce что и когда?

Tags: javascript, массивы, ecmascript-6, ecmascript

Столкнулась с тем что не понимаю когда применять метод `map` а когда `forEach`, так же постоянно встречаю `reduce`, но неясно почему выбирают его а не напрмер тот же `map`.

Кода следует использовать `map`, когда `reduce`, а когда `forEach`?

В чем их основное отличие?

Comment: Вот хорошая статья с примерами по твоему вопросу [JavaScript: Filter vs Map vs Reduce vs Foreach](https://medium.com/@stasonmars/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%85-js-filter-vs-map-vs-reduce-vs-foreach-995ef7468c4a)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Методы [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), и [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) действительно имеют много общего, что и когда использовать зависит от того, какой именно результат по итогу требуется получить.

Представим что у нас есть массив:

```
const locations = [
  {country: "Россия", population: 10},
  {country: "Китай", population: 100},
  {country: "США", population: 20}
]
```

Если нам нужно просто выполнить определенное действие для каждого элемента массива, то тут подойдет [метод forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
locations.forEach(location => {
  console.log(location)
  // мы получим три вывода в консоль
  // по одному для каждой локации
  // {country: "Россия", population: 10}
  // {country: "Китай", population: 100}
  // {country: "США", population: 20}
})

// или так, если нам нужно только определенное значение

locations.forEach(location => {
  console.log(location.country)
  // Россия
  // Китай
  // США
})

// или так, по количеству значений в массиве 

locations.forEach(() => {
  console.log("Как дела?")
  // Как дела?
  // Как дела?
  // Как дела?
})
```

Если мы хотим трансформировать наш массив и занести результаты в переменную, то тут [метод map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) будет более уместен чем forEach, поскольку первый по итогу сразу **вернет новый массив**.

Посмотрим на разницу forEach vs map в случае когда нам нужно "обернуть" каждое название страны в HTML таг:

```
// через forEach
const result = []
locations.forEach(location => {
  result.push(`<h1>${location.country}</h1>`)
})
console.log(result)
// ["<h1>Россия</h1>", "<h1>Китай</h1>", "<h1>США</h1>"]

// с использованием map
const result = locations.map(location => `<h1>${location.country}</h1>`)    
console.log(result)
// ["<h1>Россия</h1>", "<h1>Китай</h1>", "<h1>США</h1>"]
```

[Метод reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) отличается от map тем что он **возвращает финальное "значение"**.

Допустим мы хотим посчитать суммарный размер населения:

```
const result = locations.reduce((total, location) => {
  return total + location.population
}, 0)

console.log(result)
// 130
```

Это достаточно простой пример, но "финальным значением" может быть не только число, а, например, объект или массив, что делает метод reduce поистине мощным инструментом трансформаций.

Comment: @MobiDevices, пожалуйста, не изменяйте тексты ответов на основе политических взглядов. В SO политика неуместна.

Answer (score 14):

Полезно понимать, что все три метода - всего лишь встроенные циклы, которые просто выглядят симпатичнее, чем обычный цикл. Если уже ловко используете циклы, нужно просто знать, что делают эти методы, чтобы постепенно переходить на них.

**► forEach** (обычный перебор)

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3];

// --
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  console.log( "for", arr[i] );
}

// --
arr.forEach( e => console.log("forEach", e) ); // e ←→ arr[i]
```

**► map** — Создает новый массив, по очереди вызывает переданную функцию для каждого элемента исходного массива. Добавляет в созданный массив результаты вызовов этой функции.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3];

// --
let result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  result.push( arr[i] * 2 );
}
console.log(result); // [2, 4, 6]

// --
console.log( arr.map( e => e * 2 ) ); // [2, 4, 6]
```

**► reduce** — можно использовать во всех случаях, где помимо основных параметров, нужна еще одна дополнительная переменная, которая будет что-то хранить в процессе перебора.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3];

// --
let sum = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  sum += arr[i];
}
console.log(sum); // 6

// --                                         ↓ Вместо let sum = 0;
console.log( arr.reduce( (sum, e) => sum + e, 0 ) ); // 6

// Вместо объявления переменной sum, её можно встроить в одну строчку с вызовом.
// Также вызывает функцию для каждого элемента.
// То, что вернет функция - станет значением sum при следующем вызове функции.

// В конце перебора вернет итоговое значение sum.
```

---

А "внутри" происходит примерно это:

```js
Array.prototype.my_forEach = function(fn, context) {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    fn.call(context, arr[i], i, arr);
  } // Переданная функция получает "имя" fn, и вызывается через неё в цикле.
};

Array.prototype.my_map = function(fn, context) {
  let result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    result.push( fn.call(context, arr[i], i, arr) );
  } // в будущий массив добавляются результаты вызовов функции.
  
  return result;
};

Array.prototype.my_reduce = function(fn, value) {
  let i = 0;
  
  if (typeof value == "undefined") {
    if (this.length == 0) {
      throw new Error("Reduce of empty array with no initial value");
    }
    
    i = 1;
    value = this[0];
    // Если второй аргумент (объявление начального значения) не указан,
    // берется первый элемент массива вместо него.
  }
  
  for (i; i < this.length; i++) {
    value = fn(value, arr[i], i, arr);
  }
  
  return value;
};

/***/

let arr = [1, 2, 3];

arr.my_forEach( e => console.log(e) ); // 1, 2, 3

console.log( arr.my_map( e => e * 2 ) ); // [2, 4, 6]

console.log( arr.my_reduce( (sum, e) => sum + e ) ); // 6
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100vh !important; }
```

Comment: в `my_map` можешь сразу выделить массив нужно длины, потому что она не меняется

Comment: *чтобы постепенно переходить на них* — А зачем на них переходить?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Не предлагаю фанатично отказываться от классических циклов (которые иногда выглядят понятнее, чем тот же reduce), но для коротких блоков кода, на приведенных примерах видно: То, что обычным циклом делается за 3-5 строчек, можно кратко завернуть в вызов одного встроенного метода, по названию которого примерно понятно, что происходит. В цикл немного нужно всматриваться - он везде 'for' )

Answer (score 4):

Если кратко:

1. Когда нужно изменить текущий массив или использовать из него данные по очереди, не возвращая нового значения, лучше использовать `forEach()` (или цикл for-of). Пример: вывести все элементы массива в консоль по очереди.
2. Когда нужно создать и вернуть новый массив, с тем же количеством элементов, но изменив их, лучше использовать `map()`. Пример: сделать из массива строк новый массив чисел.
3. Когда нужно создать и вернуть совсем другое значение (примитив или объект), перебрав во время создания элементы массива, лучше использовать `reduce()`. Пример: вернуть сумму всех числовых элементов массива.

Answer (score 1):

FOREACH - когда у Вас "код-лапша", когда тело цикла простое - 2-5 строчек. Этот цикл легко читать.

А если код разбит на колбэки, в теле всё сложно и можно выделить это в одну функцию или там уже одна функция - то map,reduce.

MAP - применяет функцию к каждому элементу. на выходе массив той же длинны.

REDUCE - попарно берет свой результат на прошлой итерации и новый элемент из массива. На выходе одна переменная